# Styling file upload button for simple_form_for with Bootstrap in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using simple_form_for, Bootstrap and Rails 3. In a form:

`<%= f.input :upload, label: 'PDF file:' , input_html: {accept: ('application/pdf') } %>`

I don't know how I'd style this so that the "choose file" button can have a different class ('btn btn-primary').

Additionally, when using with Bootstrap at least, its severely misaligned by default. See attached image.

Finally, how do I redefine the text from "No file chosen" to "Chose file" when there isn't one added yet, and show the file name when there is one.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how I do it:

1. In the view add your form file field and hide it
2. Add a styled additional field just to display the file name
3. Add a button to trigger the file browse dialog

   ```
   <div class="control-group">
     <div class="attach-set">
       <%= f.input :real_file, input_html: { hidden: true }, label: 'Upload Attachment' %>
       <div class="input-append">
         <input id="file-display" class="input-large uneditable-input" type="text">
         <a id="upload-btn" class="btn"><i class="icon-upload-alt"></i> Browse</a>
       </div>
     </div> <!-- /attach-set -->
   </div> <!-- /control-group -->
   ```
4. In your JS (Coffee w/ jQuery shown), pass the click from the display button onto the real file input and when they select a file drop the file name in the display text field (I drop the path so that I don't see C:\FakePath....)

   ```
   $(document).ready ->

     # ------------------------------------------------------
     # pretty-fy the upload field
     # ------------------------------------------------------
     $realInputField = $('#real_file')

     # drop just the filename in the display field
     $realInputField.change ->
       $('#file-display').val $(@).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')

     # trigger the real input field click to bring up the file selection dialog
     $('#upload-btn').click ->
       $realInputField.click()
   ```

Comment: Great answer. I have only one question: what does the 'uneditable-input' class does?

Comment: uneditable-input it's a bootstrap class that just disables the input field so that the only way to change the contents is via the file picker

Comment: My file input does not seem to get hidden, does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: @Wraithseeker, The hidden: true is overwritten by display: block of input[type="file"] when I did the inspect
input[type="file"] {
1. display: block;
}
[hidden], template {
2. display: none;
}
You can add a class inside input_html: {class: 'hidden-input'} and a more specific rule in you scss:
products.scss
// Product new/edit (ie. _form)
input[type="file"].hidden-input {
    display: none;
}

Comment: I had to do this (HAML): = f.input :pic, as: :hidden, input_html: { hidden: true, type: "file", class: "file required" } to hide the original file upload box. Also, to get it readonly the "uneditable-field" class didn't work for me so I added readonly: true. Works great!

Answer (score 13):

This worked great for me and only requires HTML

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
  Add a file!
  <span style="display:none;">
    <%= f.file_field :image, required: true, multiple: true, name: 'picture' %>
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran across and am using [Jasny's extension to Bootstrap 3](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput).  It seems to work well so far.

Answer (score 4):

### No JS required, just plain css

scss

```
.fileinput-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 32px;
  input{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);
    direction: ltr;
    cursor: pointer;
  } 
}
```

---

html / slim

```
span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button"
  i.fa.fa-pencil
  span
   |  Select File
  = f.file_field :cover_ar
```

---

I recommend using compass for cross browser compatibility

Comment: You have two small typos in your CSS (one missing semicolon, one missing }), and for Safari support, it is helpful to add `-webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0)scale(4);`. Other than that, great solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As @rafaelfranca said you can't style `file` input but you can add your own button which will be clicking your hidden original button. See example here http://jsfiddle.net/rUdf2/6/

Answer (score 2):

Every Browser has a different type of file input field button and this makes it a pain. You can play a little with css. This has given me a basic styling with JS without the annoying "No file chosen" text in chrome and Safary:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".your_button").css("width", "80px");
});
```

Otherwise the best solution is to hide it and show a fake one that intercepts the click:

http://duckranger.com/2012/06/pretty-file-input-field-in-bootstrap/

With respect to the question of how to show that a file has been uploaded, a basic solution with jquery file upload is to detect the upload complete event and replace some of your text with a success message (The exact file name I believe it is not possible to obtain with modern browsers):

```
$(".your_button").fileupload({
    dataType: "json",
    done: function(e, data) {
        $(".place_for_your_text").text("File uploaded.");
    }
});
```

In summary, a basic solution is to use javascript in your assets to:

1. Hide the annoying "No file chosen text" with css.
2. Place your "Chose file" text next to the button and give it a class you can reference.
3. Replace the text with "File uploaded"

Answer (score 0):

No fancy shiz required:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/admin/image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<%= boxes[i].url %>" />
    <input class="image-file-chosen" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input class="btn image-file-button" value="Choose Image" />
    <input class="image-file hide" type="file" name="image"/> <!-- Hidden -->
    <br />
    <br />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="image" value="Upload" />
    <br />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.image-file-button').each(function() {
      $(this).off('click').on('click', function() {
           $(this).siblings('.image-file').trigger('click');
      });
});
$('.image-file').each(function() {
      $(this).change(function () {
           $(this).siblings('.image-file-chosen').val(this.files[0].name);
      });
});
```

CAUTION: The three form elements in question MUST be siblings of each other (.image-file-chosen, .image-file-button, .image-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, Simple Forms, Jasny, and ReFile, this post may be of interest to you [refile simple_form undefined method attachment_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285939/refile-simple-form-undefined-method-attachment-field/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="btn btn-primary"
<%= f.input :upload, label: 'PDF file:',
class:"hidden", input_html: {accept: ('application/pdf') } %>
</label>
```

Works for me

Using class="hidden"

PS: I'm using Tailwind CSS