# Unable to style Rails form file_field using Tailwindcss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a Rails 7 application using Tailwindcss. What i'm trying to achieve is to style a `file_field` form field using a TailwindUI component. This is the code for the field component in tailwind:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/B87tupVjOn

What I did is to replace the HTML input field

```
<input id="file-upload" name="file-upload" type="file" class="sr-only">
```

with the Rails form field and add a class `hidden` to it.

```
f.file_field :photo, multiple: false, class: "hidden"
```

This is the outcome it gave me:
[image]

However, using the `hidden` class as suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509449/styling-file-upload-button-for-simple-form-for-with-bootstrap-in-rails-3) doesn't work. I think is maybe because the browser recognizes the hidden class in an input file and doesn't allow the upload operation.

The area around the dashed border should be clickable but doesn't work either. When I inspect the input element, it is not selectable from the `Upload a file` section. Something else I tried is using opacity 0 to hide it but it doesn't work.

How can I replace `<input id="file-upload" name="file-upload" type="file" class="sr-only">` with the Rails `f.file_field` so I'm able to use the upload a file component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clicking the input, you're clicking the `label` which doesn't match the input `id` anymore. Just replace *<label>* tag to match the input:

```
f.label :photo, "Upload a file", class: "label"
f.file_field :photo, multiple: false, class: "sr-only"
```

*input* is already hidden by *sr-only* class; visible only to screen readers.